# I saw no one / I didn’t see anyone

Tags: meaning, grammar, phrases, meaning-in-context

> I saw no one / I didn’t see anyone.

We can’t use double negatives, but is there any difference between these sentences?

Comment: There's a subtle difference - the first is a bit more emphatic - but they're otherwise equivalent. [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+saw+no+one%2CI+didn%27t+see+anyone&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20saw%20no%20one%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20did%20not%20see%20anyone%3B%2Cc0) shows that "didn't see / did not see" (the ngram collapses the 2 into one search) has increased in popularity over the last 40 years in particular. Interesting to compare US vs UK usage too...

Answer (score 1):

Other than "I saw no one" being a bit more literary, no, no difference.

Comment: Colin, this is a bit on the short side, and I'm sure you're aware that brief answers go to the LQ queue. Any chance of a bit more detail or explanation? Otherwise it might have been better as a comment...

Comment: @Chappo: Colin has enough credibility around here by now that most of us are willing to extend him the benefit of the doubt in cases like this one.

Comment: One way in which it is a bit more literary is that when (as here) there is a choice between negating the verb and negating its object, it is more idiomatic to negate the verb. I'm referring here to English in a normal register, not literary.